# Update different table when row inserted

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a marketplace platform, where I store user balances as a table of balance changes, along with a precalculated value in their user row. This allows me to check their balance easily, but still recalculate at specific intervals to ensure they stay in sync.

Here is an example of what the balance change table might look like:

```
| id | opening_balance | closing_balance | user_id |
|----|-----------------|-----------------|---------|
| 1  | 23.40           | 28.20           | 6       |
| 2  | 14.70           | 11.10           | 79      |
| 3  | 117.12          | 107.12          | 20      |
```

When a new row is inserted, I want to update the `balance` column on the `user_id` relation to the newly inserted `closing_balance`.

From what I've found online, I've got the following however it's for MySQL rather than Postgresql.

```
CREATE TRIGGER balance_update
AFTER INSERT ON balance_history
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE users 
     SET balance = NEW.closing_balance
   WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
END;
```

It looks like Postgresql requires you create a named procedure before creating a trigger? Not sure the best way to convert this.

Comment: See the examples in the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers in Postgres have a syntax a bit more complex than MySQL, because they execute procedures as the action.  In this case, we can define a function which will perform the update you want as a result of the insert on the first table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_proc()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE users 
    SET balance = NEW.closing_balance
    WHERE id = NEW.user_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER balance_update
AFTER INSERT ON balance_history
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE your_proc();
```

Comment: @BenedictLewis Typo, I had `RETURN NEW` instead of `RETURN NEW;` with a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Ah, I'm now getting `syntax error at or near "RETURN"`

Comment: I'm out of ideas, it should work.  Did you define everything in the correct place?

Comment: Worked out what it was, table was `user` not `users`, so needed to be quoted

Comment: @BenedictLewis Glad you figured it out.  I assumed the problem would be something like this.